# Registros en MySQL se guardan con saltos de línea

Tags: php, mysql, sql, md5

Tengo un pequeño script en **PHP** el cual me lee las líneas de un archivo de texto y luego una por una me las va ingresando en una columna, aquí les dejo el script.

```
<?php 

    require("sql/db.php");

    $file = fopen("lista.txt", "r") or exit("Error abriendo fichero!");

    while($linea = fgets($file)) {
        $arreglo = array(md5($linea));

        foreach ($arreglo as $datos){
            mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO hashs (ench,dech) VALUES ('$datos','$linea')");
        }
    }

?>
```

Como pudieron observar, además de guardar las líneas, guarda esta misma línea pero encriptada en **Md5**. Las columnas son la siguientes: **id, ench, dech** y la tabla se llama **hashs**. Mi problema es el siguiente. Los registros se guardan con un salto de línea, es decir, como si se presionara enter despues de cada palabra, y esto no me es factible porque con ese espacio el hash resulta totalmente diferente.

Aclaro que, las líneas en crudo se guardan en **dech** y los hashs en **ench**. Utilizo **Phpmyadmin 4.7.4** como gestor de BD. Acoto que este proyecto no pienso subirlo a internet ni nada por el estilo, es un programa personal, local, asi que eviten comentar cosas entorno a la seguridad por favor.

Comment: fgets($file) retorna la fila con el salto de línea incluído, si no lo quieres en la base de datos, quítalo antes de hacer el insert. Sería algo así como $linea = trim(preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $linea));

Comment: Excelente, funciona a la perfección, gracias, deberías publicarlo como respuesta y no como comentario.

Comment: En realidad no, eso evocaría a un trabajo de búsqueda y aprendizaje que ahora mismo no me interesa, lo dejo para otro o para más adelante si tengo tiempo. Pero gracias igualmente.

Comment: Vale compredo. Ya se puede dar por resuelta mi problemática.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Respuesta adaptada de este [comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/149433/registros-en-mysql-se-guardan-con-saltos-de-l%C3%ADnea#comment279847_149433):

`fgets($file)` retorna la fila con el salto de línea incluido, si no lo quieres en la base de datos, quítalo antes de hacer el insert.

Sería algo así como:

```
$linea = trim(preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $linea));
```

Comment: Por qué volver tu aporte un wiki?

Comment: @Aprendiz para no ganar reputación por ello.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar [`trim()`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.trim.php) para eliminar los siguientes caracteres del principio y final de un string:

```
" " (ASCII 32 (0x20)), espacio simple.
"\t" (ASCII 9 (0x09)), tabulación.
"\n" (ASCII 10 (0x0A)), salto de línea.
"\r" (ASCII 13 (0x0D)), retorno de carro.
"\0" (ASCII 0 (0x00)), el byte NUL.
"\x0B" (ASCII 11 (0x0B)), tabulación vertical.
```

Si solo quieres eliminarlos del final, puedes utilizar un hermano de trim llamado [`rtrim()`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.rtrim.php), tambien existe [`ltrim()`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.ltrim.php) para hacer lo mismo solo al principio del string.

Ejemplo :

```
<?php
$file = fopen("archivo.txt", "r") or exit("Error abriendo fichero!");

while($linea = fgets($file)) {
    $linea = trim($linea);
    echo $linea;
    /* Código */
}
```

---

Otra opción, podría ser el uso de  [`stream_get_line()`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.stream-get-line.php) en lugar de [`fgets()`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.fgets.php), ya que `stream_get_line()` nos permite establecer un delimitador que no sera devuelto.

Ejemplo:

```
<?php
$file = fopen("archivo.txt", "r") or exit("Error abriendo fichero!");

while($linea = stream_get_line($file, 65535, '\r\n')) {
    echo $linea;
    /* Código */
}
```